# Set two different colours to single container

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to achieve a custom design dynamically from my button. I have designed this button from a Container with InkWell. But I am not getting a correct way how I can set 2 different colours to this button based on received values from my API.
For reference here is the button:
[image]

In this button grey part is container background color. Then I added a image in this container. Now the red color should dynamic with height received from server. 
But I am not getting a correct way how I can do it.

Comment: use `Stack` with 2 children: gray `Image` + `ClipRect` that clips red `Image`

Comment: take a color variable, change it's value as per the api results the setState

Comment: Actually I am asking different thing and you are proposing different solution. Let me tell you more specific, I need to use 2 different colors in Container as showing in image. The icon is different thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it using `gradient` but in case you want to create your own `Container` to get more customization,  here you have:

```
class MyCustomContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final Color progressColor;
  final double progress;
  final double size;

  const MyCustomContainer({
    Key key,
    this.backgroundColor = Colors.grey,
    this.progressColor = Colors.red,
    @required this.progress,
    @required this.size,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(size / 2),
      child: SizedBox(
        height: size,
        width: size,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: backgroundColor,
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Container(
                height: size * progress,
                color: progressColor,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
Center(
        child: MyCustomContainer(
          progress: 0.7,
          size: 100,
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          progressColor: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
```

**Result**

[image]

And of course you can customize that widget to receive a `child` and put it at the center.

Comment: Thanks for your perfect explanation which saved my lot of hours.

Comment: @diegoveloper Thanks dear, it worked like charm :)

Answer (score 19):

You can easily achieve this with container and linear gradient. Pass in the colors as gradient and define appropriate stops at the required percentages.

Example:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final Color background = Colors.grey;
  final Color fill = Colors.redAccent;
  final List<Color> gradient = [
    background,
    background,
    fill,
    fill,
  ];
  final double fillPercent = 56.23; // fills 56.23% for container from bottom
  final double fillStop = (100 - fillPercent) / 100;
  final List<double> stops = [0.0, fillStop, fillStop, 1.0];

  return Container(
    child: Icon(Icons.forward),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        colors: gradient,
        stops: stops,
        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Hope this helps!