# Flutter half circle with multiple fill colors

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-custompainter

I would like to create this in Flutter:

[image]

I know you can create a half circle like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57748469/flutter-how-to-draw-semicircle-half-circle).

But how I can get these multiple fill colors?

I know there is way to get this done with `LinearGradient`. ([something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57068825/set-two-different-colours-to-single-container))

But this might work, but I need to **each color-section as a separated part/widget** because I want to animate them in the next step.

How could I get this done?

Comment: Have you looked at [`CustomPaint`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using Custom Painter but then I understand it would be challenging to animate each color bar. I have been able to create something like you need

[image: demo]

I used the ClipRRect widget to cut out the bottomLeft and bottomRight portions of a square -> SemiCircle.

Each Color bar is a Container and since you would like to animate each bar you can easily replace the Container with an AnimatedContainer and proceed from there. You might also need to make the widget stateful for animations.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Assuming constraints here. 
    // Play with width and height values 
    const double widgetWidth = 100;
    const double widgetHeight = 60;
    // To get a semicircle
     const double bottomRadius = widgetWidth / 2;
    //Since we have 5 colors . Each color bars height is 60/5 = 12
    const double colorBarHeight = widgetHeight / 5;

return ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(bottomRadius),
        bottomRight: Radius.circular(bottomRadius)),
    child: SizedBox(
        width: widgetWidth,
        height: widgetHeight,
        child: Column(
          children: [
          Container(
              width: widgetWidth,height: colorBarHeight,color: Colors.green),
          Container(
              width: widgetWidth,height: colorBarHeight,color: Colors.orange),
          Container(
              width: widgetWidth,height: colorBarHeight,color: Colors.yellow),
          Container(
              width: widgetWidth, height: colorBarHeight, color: Colors.red),
          Container(
              width: widgetWidth, height: colorBarHeight, color: Colors.blue),
        ])));
```

}
}

Comment: change the `widgetHeight` to 50 and then it is working perfeclty! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this below code:

```
class SemiCircle extends StatelessWidget {
  const SemiCircle({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(300),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(300),
              ),
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                height: 100,
                width: 200,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 10,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 10,
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 10,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 10,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 10,
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 10,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 10,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 10,
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 10,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 10,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You will get an output like below:

[image]

Comment: working as expected, thanks for your answer :) cant mark both as answers :D they are pretty much the same. thanks :)